# Reflexive, symmetric, and transitive closures

Tags: relations, order-theory

The problem: [image: here]

I am having difficulty with this problem. How do I even start? I know what reflexive, symmetric and transitive closures intuitively mean but I am struggling to find s(r(R)), (symmetric closure OF reflexive closure of R) for example. Do I even have to find out all the specific elements of s(r(R)) or do I just use a more general method?

I deduced that all elements of R are as follows: [elements in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuW9E.jpg), where the columns are primes and the rows are the nth multiple of the prime. (Can someone verify this?) [image: elements in R]

And I know that r(R) (reflexive closure of R) is the union of R with the set { (0,0), (1,1) , (2,2), (3,3) ... }.

But I am having difficulty listing out all the elements in s(r(R)) and r(s(R)) so that I can solve part (a), for example.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is the set of paired natural numbers $(x,y)$ where $y=px$ for some $p$ which is a prime number.$$R=\{(x,px):x\in\Bbb N, p\in\Bbb P\}$$

> And I know that r(R) (reflexive closure of R) is the union of R with the set { (0,0), (1,1) , (2,2), (3,3) ... }.

Yes.  Thus the reflexive closure is therefore defined:$$\begin{split}r(R):&=\{(x,px):x\in\Bbb N, p\in\Bbb P\}\cup\{(x,x):x\in\Bbb N\}\\&= \{(x,qx):x\in\Bbb N,q\in\Bbb P\cup\{1\}\}\end{split}$$... or in words: the set of paired natural numbers $(x,y)$ where $y=qx$ for some $q$ which is a prime number *or* $1$.

In the same manner, describe the symmetric closure, $s(R)$, and likewise $r(s(R))$ and $s(r(R))$.